# assign increasing integer values to a list of variables without having to count the number of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry

I have some old code, that implements following pattern.

It declares `n` constants within the class, which have values from `0` to `n-1`.

```
class FSM:
    ST_INITIAL, ST_FIRST, ST_SECOND = range(3)
    def __init__(...):
        self.state = self.ST_INITIAL
    def step(self):
        if self.STATE == self.ST_INITIAL:
            blabla
        elif self.state == self.ST_FIRST:
            blabla
```

Now if there are many values (if `n` is a large number it is no fun having to count how many variables one wants to declare in order to fill in the right value of `n` into the `range()` function)

What I wanted to know is whether there is any feature in any of the newer python versions (> 2.7), that allows to write something like:

```
a, b, c, d = xxxxxxx  #
```

without having to count, that `a, b, c, d` is a list of identifiers with `4` values and being forced to add the `4` on the right hand side of the expression.

```
a, b, c, d = range(4)  # the 4 on the right hand side of the expression is 
                       # what I want to get rid of.
```

Comment: I wondered if following question title would be better.

**assign increasing integer values to a list of variables without having to count the number of variables**

Comment: It's not good idea to assign each value to separate name. You may convert `range` object to list or other container type though.

Comment: It's always better to have the question title be the actual question you're asking.

Comment: yes I agree with previous comments, your "constants" are variables anyways, just create a more dynamic approach such as list if you want to keep them in this way

Answer (score 0):

It's *not nice*, but you could do the following:

```
a, b, c, d, *tmp = range(100) # large enough to cover all possibilites
del tmp                       # tmp is just a buffer that takes all the unwanted numbers
```

Re your comment: This

```
tmp = range(100)

a, b, c, d, *tmp = tmp
i, j, k, l, m, *tmp = tmp

print(a, b, c, d)
print(i, j, k, l, m)
```

leads to

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8
```

Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: true that works. 

however the unfortunate thuing is, that *tmp consumes all the remaining values.


I guess, there is now way, that tmp 'just' acts as a generator and doesn't consume all remaining values.

Comment: No my comment just meant just, that `tmp` is expanded into a fully blown list (that is of course deleted afterwards) but it means I have to put a max value that is high enough and accept the intermittent (non critical) waste of memory and list creation.

But I agree, I didn't find any better solution.

Comment: @gelonida Understood! As I said, it's not nice, I wouldn't do it myself.

Comment: just added another ugly solution. 

At the moment the lesser evil (concerning readability) is probably really to hardcode
the length

Answer (score 0):

One also ugly solution might be:

To transform:

```
class FSM:
    ST_INITIAL, ST_FIRST, ST_SECOND = range(3)
    def __init__(...):
```

into:

```
class FSM:
    STATE_NAMES = ("ST_INITIAL", "ST_FIRST", "ST_SECOND")
    def __init__(...):


for ctr, name in enumerate(FSM.STATE_NAMES):
   setattr(FSM, name, ctr)
```